# Connection reset by peer - Bad protocol version identification '\272\334

Tags: ssh

I am getting an error of `Connection reset by peer` when trying to communicate with a VME card through a single board computer with [ORCA](http://orca.physics.unc.edu/~markhowe/Orca_Help/Home.html). Checking `/var/log/auth` gives me the error `Bad protocol version identification '\272\334`.

Everything that I have seen suggests that the error comes from different versions of SSH. Running `ssh -v` gives the following:

ORCA Computer:  `OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011`

SBC: `OpenSSH_4.7p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007`

I was wondering if there are any known issues when communicating between these two versions or if something else could cause the error. Unfortunately, updating the versions of SSH on either machine is not really an option. The SBC is connected to the other computer via a private network and the SBC has no outside access, so there aren't really any security issues that are necessary to look for.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the client sends something that is not an SSH protocol identifier. You might want to check what it actually sends with TCPdump and/or Wireshark.